# How to make TextBox scrollable in WPF

Tags: wpf, textbox, scroll

I using one header control in wpf application in that I am using Grid and in that grid I am putting List box some buttons
and text box. I want to make that text box scrollable. Can you please give me the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a TextBox, set its following properties:

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

You said:

> I have tried this but it is not working

```
<Label Content="Log Details" Grid.Row="4" ></Label>
<Border Margin="7,7,7,3" Grid.Row="5">
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="5" > 
    <StackPanel >
      <TextBox Margin="5" AcceptsReturn="True"
               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsReadOnly="True" 
               x:Name="LogDetails" /> 
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

> I am putting this in headercontrol. – jolly

Actually, you don't need to put a TextBox into a ScrollViewer since TextBox already has a ScrollViewer associated in its Template.

But if you are having your specific requirement in which you need to do the same, you can try something like this:

```
<Label Content="Log Details" Grid.Row="4" ></Label>
<Border Margin="7,7,7,3" Grid.Row="5">
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="5" >
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBox Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap"
               AcceptsReturn="True" IsReadOnly="True"
               x:Name="LogDetails" />
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Textbox/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working

  <Label Content="Log Details" Grid.Row="4" ></Label>
        <Border  Margin="7,7,7,3" Grid.Row="5">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="5" >
            <StackPanel >
                        <TextBox Margin="5" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="LogDetails"></TextBox> </StackPanel>  </ScrollViewer> 
</Border> I am putting this in headercontrol.